# Hi everyone, i am posting one image. Can we do the same with the dataset using python for hierarchical data

Tags: python, dataframe, visualization, ag-grid, exploratory-data-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9BJr.jpg)

This is the image in which we can see that in first column 'location hierarchy' there are many drop down option.
If we start from fy 2020 under which we have continents and under that we have countries.
Is it possible using python and its libraries.

Comment: Hi sembei norimaki , could you please tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

Use Python's pandas and tkinter libraries together to organize the data into a dropdown menu. You can use pandas to read and manipulate the data, using tkinter alongside it to create dynamic dropdown options for the hierarchical data you have. Also, you may be asking if you can create dropdowns inside dropdowns; the answer is yes. So to answer your overall question (which was a bit vague), **yes.** It is possible to recreate this hierarchical data in Python.

Comment: I am creating one web api using streamlit library of python so if we are printing dataset so i want those drop down with that dataset as shown in image. Will our tkinter able to do this?